# More than one Modal Boxes on one page

Tags: javascript, html

Here I put in 2 buttons where clicking these would popup a modal box.

```
 <li type="button" id="myBtn" class="w3-hide-small w3-center"><a href="#" class="w3-hover-white">1</a></li>
 <li type="button" id="myBtn2" class="w3-hide-small w3-center"><a href="#" class="w3-hover-white">2</a></li>
```

Here's the modal information for week one:

```
<!-- MODAL INFORMATION FOR WEEK 1  -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">×</span>
    <p><h2><font color="black">Week 1</font></h2></p>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><font color="black"> ex1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here's the modal information for week two:**

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">×</span>
    <p><h2><font color="black">Week 2</font></h2></p>
      <p><font color="black"> Example 1 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I thought that changing the ID would allow me to treat the modal boxes differently from one another, and also that i'm calling "Btn" and "Btn2" differently.

When I click on 1 and 2, they both open up the same text from week one and 2.

Comment: You should use Bootstrap jQuery methods to open modals in JavaScript (`display.block` won't open your modal). And your HTML doesn't look like Bootstrap modals.

Comment: Change for dialog is better https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Comment: "you should use Bootstrap"? Modals can easily be created without Bootstraps bloat!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing the same content is because you are targeting the same modal:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block"; <--- should be modal2
}
```

Comment: When I change it to model2 it ended up not working altogether. I mean 1 still works, but for 2 nothing happens even when clicked. I also tried changing the class for modal 2 to modal2 instead of modal.

Comment: I would inspect the page to see what is happening to modal2, from what i can see it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a data attribute for the modal. You need to same `id` in your modal with the same `data-target` for the button

ex

```
<!-- MODAL INFORMATION FOR WEEK 1  -->
<div id="myModalA" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">×</span>
    <p><h2><font color="black">Week 1</font></h2></p>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><font color="black"> ex1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">×</span>
    <p><h2><font color="black">Week 2</font></h2></p>
      <p><font color="black"> Example 1 </p>
  </div>
</div>


 <li type="button" id="myBtn" class="w3-hide-small w3-center" data-target="myModalA"><a href="#" class="w3-hover-white">1</a></li>


 <li type="button" id="myBtn2" class="w3-hide-small w3-center" data-target="myModal2"><a href="#" class="w3-hover-white">2</a></li>
```

Comment: I believe this could work, but I'm having an odd problem where my data-target isn't being registered. It's still in black text when it should've turned red. Using notepad++.